glibc testing framework: how can I use the -p option to execute only tests matching a part of the argument?
I am using g_test_init to initialise a test and now I want to use the -p option to only execute part of the tests. Is it possible to use wildcards or is it possible only to use one specific path?
My glibc version is 2.35.
The manual says:

-p PATH: Execute all tests matching the given path.

Here's my code:
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    g_test_init (&argc, &argv, NULL);



    g_test_add_func("/char_funcs/isalpha", isalpha_test);
    g_test_add_func("/char_funcs/isdigit", isdigit_test);
    g_test_add_func("/put_fd/putchar/test1_stdout", putchar_test1);
    g_test_add_func("/put_fd/putchar/test2", putchar_test2);
    
    return (g_test_run());
}

Now when I type
./test

all four tests get executed.
When I type
./test -p /put_fd/putchar/test1_stdout

only this single test gets executed.
So far so good.
Now when I want to execute both of the put_fd tests, I tried:
./test -p /put_fd

or
./test -p "/put_fd/*"

nothing gets executed. How can I use the p option to execute only the two put_fd/putchar tests? Or is this not possible?
